# Locate text in string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a string of varying length taken from a MySQL database and in that string is a value (in bold below):

s:1:"4", s:2:"53", **s:3:"7"**, s:4:"5"

I need a way to find whatever is in quotes following the **s:3:**. So in this example, it would be **7**. I've looked around and I think I need to use the explode function but I am having trouble implementing it. The string may contain multiple values of this in which case I'd like to get them all into an array.

Comment: Show us what you found and where you had trouble implementing it.

Comment: Where is this string coming from originally?

Comment: Sounds like a good use for `preg_match_all()`.

Comment: First of all, **post your code, not your problem accompanied by an idea**. P.S. This looks like a serialized PHP array saved in database (common bad practice for saving varying length of data inside database). If it is what I suspect then use `unserialize()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) for that:

```
$str = 's:1:"4", s:2:"53", s:3:"7", s:4:"5"';

if(preg_match_all('/s:3:"(.*?)"/', $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: he said it can appear multiple times, so you need to use `preg_match_all`.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ It's needed to prevent greedy matching.

Comment: @Barmar Oh yeah, sorry, was thinking of doing it a different way. I don't normally use the greedy method.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ You can test it without. It will not work. It is needed to prevent greedy matching of the `"`. It's the *lazy quantifier*

Comment: @hek2mgl I've posted what I thought you wrote... guess everyone writes code differently.

Comment: @Barmar, I usually don't use the greedy quantifiers when I write these... I posted what I thought he had written in my answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for the fast reply! This works but I have one more question. I am new to PHP so forgive me. Let's say I want to print just the first value, I would think it would be:echo $matches[0]; but this gives the error: Notice: Array to string conversion. How do I reference the value in this case?

Comment: Then use `$matches[1][0]`. If you need the second use `$matches[1][1]` and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

Non-greedy method, includes multi-lines.

```
<?php 
  $str = 's:1:"4", s:2:"53", s:3:"7", s:4:"5"';

  if(preg_match_all('!s:3:"([^"]+)"!s', $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
  }

?>
```